# Downloading zombies

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I got the season pass for advanced warfare and your supposed to get all the dlc's when they come out. I downloaded atlas gorge. Zombies came out a couple weeks ago. How do I download Advanced warfare zombies? Im on ps3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exo-Zombies only just came out a few days ago for Xbox platforms only, you have to wait a while (usually a month) before other platforms can purchase/download Call of Duty DLCs.

> Beginning Jan. 27, those playing Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare on Xbox will be able to purchase and download the $15 Havoc DLC; a collection of post-launch content that both introduces Exo Zombies and fleshes out the game's current collection of competitive multiplayer maps. After 30 days, those playing Advanced Warfare on PlayStation 3, PS4 and/or PC will also be given a chance to buy the Havoc DLC and check out the latest iteration of Call of Duty's love-it-or-hate-it Zombies mode.

[source](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/call-duty-advanced-warfare-havoc-dlc-release-date-and-launch-timelines-revealed-404453)